# How can I stop the installation of prerequisites to pop every time in advanced installer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, advanced-installer

I am creating the deployment project (.MSI) for my .NET Windows project (Visual Studio 2010) using the advanced installer 8.x by adding some driver and 3rd party SDKs. I added them as prerequisites by choosing the product keys as conditions, but when I run the project it’s popping the prerequisites even after they get installed. Its status is not changing to installed and popping up every time.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisites use detection criteria to determine if they are installed or not. So most likely your prerequisite install conditions are not correct.

Usually a prerequisite is detected by searching for a file or registry entry installed by it. To see what files and registry entries are installed by a package you can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) or a repackager tool.